# customizing d3.js brush as slider

Tags: d3.js, slider

I am trying to follow the below example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972 and i ve not been very successful in understanding the specifics involved. Would be great if someone can help me in explaining where the co ordinates and size of the slider can be customized? ps I am new to d3 and javascript :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the size of the slider using the margin and size properties:

```
var margin = {top: 100, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 50},
width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 200 - margin.bottom - margin.top;
```

JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/kihasebenu/1/edit)

Comment: But how do i change the x,y pos of the entire slider? currently the slider appears in the center page of the browser.

Comment: The slider is in a box. The box is the SVG element. The SVG element is just like any other HTML element. To modifiy the position of the slider you must arrange your elements in the appropriate manner: http://jsbin.com/boretonima/2/edit?html,css,js,output . Hope this helps.

Comment: i am trying to reduce the 0-180 slider range as 0-5 it reduces to the need, but then the scale changes in term of 0.5 say 0.5,1,1.5 ... 5 how do i control this range?

Comment: I was asking about the value on the display rather than the result? say if we set the range as 0,5 instead of 0,30 the scale displays in terms of 0.5 increments.. how can we control that?